# Why is a div longer than several spans with the same content (only in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-family

I have two lines of 10000 "." in a monospace font. The first has the whole line in a div, the second is made up of 1000 spans of 10 "."'s each. Here is the JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fojp5e9z/2/

Here it is with 5000 characters, it is slightly noticeable at the end. At 10000 you get 2 full periods extra length on the top line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div style='font-family:monospace'>
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
</div>
<div style='font-family:monospace'>
<span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span>
</div></body></html>
```

In Chrome, this first line is longer than the other, but in every other browser, the lines are the same length. Even adding normalize.css doesn't help.

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it in chrome so the lines are the same length?

Comment: Remove monospace font and it works fine.

Comment: @Huangism The dots are just a placeholder. It needs to be a monospace font so that heterogeneous characters align as well.

Comment: I suppose your DNA sequence looks good now? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is due to some rounding and complex calculation. First, here is a better illustration of the problem using gradient to see the difference between both cases:

```css
span:nth-child(odd) {
  background:green;
}
span:nth-child(even) {
  background:yellow;
}
.grad {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 5ch,yellow 5ch,yellow 10ch);
}
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<div style='font-family:monospace;display:inline-block;' class="grad">
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
</div>
<div style='font-family:monospace;display:inline-block;background:red;' >
<span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span><span>.....</span>
</div>
```

We can clearly see that the top gradient is not following the coloration of the spans. I guess it's because the width of a monospace character (`1ch`) which is equal to `7.14063px` (when testing with Chrome) make the calculation somehow different in both cases.

In the upper div we will sum this value 5000 times then we do the rounding BUT in the lower div will sum this value for each span (5 times) then we round then we will sum again and round again.<sup>**1**</sup>

Of course, I don't have any formal proof of this but if we change the `font-size` to another value it will get fixed (changing the `font-size` will of course change the value of `1ch`).

Here is an test when making the `font-size:16px`.

https://jsfiddle.net/1gLejzb3/20/ <sup>**2**</sup>

---

As a side note, when testing on Firefox the `1ch` is equal to `8px` which explain why we don't have issue there since it's easy to deal with integers AND only chrome seems to work with non-integer values for the `ch` unit with fonts. So the same problem may also happen with other `font-family`.

In order to avoid such situations, better rely on a font that behave the same in all the browsers. For a monospace font I usually rely on [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata). Its `1ch` is by default equal to `8px` in all the browser (even in chrome).

https://jsfiddle.net/1gLejzb3/23/ <sup>**2**</sup>

With this `font-family` the `1ch` unit will be equal to half the `font-size` so `16px` will give `8px`, `17px` will give `8.5px` (for Fierfox it will be `8px`) and so on. If you avoid the odd values in chrome you won't have issues.

<sup>**1**: it's a simple guess as I don't know how the browser handle calculation in each case.</sup>

<sup>**2**: I am using JSfiddle because I have reached the limit of character within an answer.</sup>

Comment: Very interesting... It seems to work perfectly at 16, 32, 48, and 64, so my hypothesis would be a calculation involving dividing by 16 into a `float` in one of the cases.  "Animated" version: https://jsfiddle.net/1gLejzb3/43/

Comment: @Thymine I don't agree a lot, if it works fine with 16 then it should work also fine with 32 since we will multiply everything by 2 so we won't have issue with rounding .. same thing with 48 and 64 ... So it's not exactly the font-size but the width of each character which is the 1ch unit  ... and of course 1ch is defined by the font-size and font-family

Comment: Oh I didn't read your second section there closely enough, that does make a lot of sense. I also just realized it seems the `<span>` line is always shorter or equal to the `<div>`, which if anything means by "rounding" they just `floor` at some point. (now tempted to delete my comment haha)  We could add evidence to your hypothesis by increasing/decreasing the number of dots in each `<span>` which should decrease/increase the effect respectively

Comment: @Thymine yes I also thought about increasing/decreasing the number of dots and have a kind of pyramid but it's a lot of work :p .. maybe will edit the answer when I have time to add this part ;)