# Contiguous █ character produces colored line in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I was trying some things when I found this result:

```js
let s = "";
for (let y = 0; y < 224; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 361; x++) {
    s += '█';
  }
  s += "\n"
}
document.getElementById('r').innerText = s;
```

```css
#r {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 896px;
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="r">
</div>
```

You should see some white vertical lines along with the █ character which fills the div; this is caused by a little space in the char itself.

But more interesting, if I try this in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gogubawogi/edit?html,output) or in a plain page, the lines appear to be colored, with what appears to be a rainbow-like palette.
[image: image example of coloured lines]

I would like to know what causes this behaviour (I'm not trying to achieve something specific; I just would like to know why this happens).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what color you are seeing? On my display it seems to appear as black still when running on JSBin

Comment: @DakotaMaker I'm seeing this on the jsbin https://i.imgur.com/IrnOBJY.jpg

Comment: I agree with Arthur Wietzorek's answer that it is probably a (sub)pixel-thing.

Comment: What browser were you using @Tschallacka

Comment: chrome 67.0.3396.99 64 bit , windows 7 pro 64 bit

Comment: @DakotaMaker I'd think it's more related to your screen than your browser. If it's a subpixel rendering thing, it may be related to high DPI screens.

Comment: This seems to be chrome-specific. I can reproduce on the latest build of chromium and google chrome but not on firefox or edge.

Comment: @TomM: I'm also seeing this [on FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDaPX.png). Not on IE.

Comment: @Cerbrus I can confirm. Firefox on 80% zoom displays colored lines for me too.

Comment: Possible related question: [Sub-Pixels calculated and rendered differently among browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34676263/1220550)

Comment: it reminds me another problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294240/why-is-a-div-longer-than-several-spans-with-the-same-content-only-in-chrome/51294909#51294909

Comment: @DakotaMaker: imgur uploads expire. They disappear. stack.imgur uploads _never_ expire. Don't change the uploaded image!

Comment: Tizio, please stop accepting that edit.

Comment: Sorry @Cerbrus https://imgur.com/a/LQfanST this is what I was seeing and I was unaware that imgur uploads expire

Comment: @DakotaMaker: That's because imgur seems to have some localized issues. That will get fixed eventually.

Comment: Try it with `-webkit-font-smoothing: none`.

Answer (score 7):

I gonna have a wild guess and say its a browser specific shader thing. If you zoom in and out the colors change, so it seems that there are too few pixels to correctly show the white line. Practically the shader wants to display multiple things at the same time in one pixel, a mix of white and black, which apparently gives a different color depenting on the position on the screen?

Or maybe its even on purpose and someone thought such a shader that mixes colors of adjacent pixels to smooth everything looks better.

EDIT:
To sum up some comments, it seems that this depends on the browser your using as well as on your hardware/system, as everybody seems to get different results on different browsers. Playing around with the zoom in the browser also yields different results, for me, in Firefox, there are white horizontal lines, but on some zoom levels the vertical rainbow lines appear, too.

Comment: Yea, the gap is less than a pixel in width.

Comment: To add credence to this, the colours don't appear in Firefox - https://i.imgur.com/BzuMw6M.png

Comment: @DerekH In Firefox i have these lines on some zoom levels, but mostly horizontal, white lines

Comment: @Cerbrus I am sure the white line is a part of the character

Comment: @TemaniAfif: seems to depend on the browser rendering the character.