# CSS linear Gradient Problem on Goolge Chrome Broswer version 69.0.3497.100

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

I am using CSS liner Gradient but chrome browser some problem

older version & another browser working fine

My CSS

```
 body {
    background: #000;
}

.time-bar-block {
    display: flex;
}

.time-bar {
    border-right: 1px solid #545454;
    height: 41px;
}

.time-bar {
    background: #545454;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999 1px, #000 1px, #000 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px), #000 calc(100% - 5px), #000 100%, #999 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #999 1px, #000 1px, #000 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px), #000 calc(100% - 5px), #000 100%, #999 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999 1px, #000 1px, #000 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) 5px, rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px), #000 calc(100% - 5px), #000 100%, #999 100%);
}

.time-bar .inner {
    width: 12.75px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Firfox working fine

[image]

Problem Google chrome

[image]

Every 4 block problem

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vo6L7jcz/17/

Comment: 12.75px you say? Hm.

Comment: @MrLister although [a pixel is not a pixel](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: @D.Schaller My theory is that this works perfectly fine on a 4dppx phone.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle in the same Chrome version on Windows, and it looks fine. However, when I zoom out 1 step I see what you see. So, reset your zooming.

Comment: @MrLister what you say not getting

Comment: @KIKOSoftware reset your zooming -  done, same problem

Comment: what if Chrome is correct? chrome always do some complex rounding ... here a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294240/why-is-a-div-longer-than-several-spans-with-the-same-content-only-in-chrome/51294909#51294909

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I'm saying that changing the width to 13px - or any whole number - solves the problem. At least, it gets rid of the differences.

Comment: @MrLister yes but not considering the whole number of width, I can change this width other problem getting